# Can I test a (spring) controller in a library

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing

I have created a java-module which contains a Controller. The module can be used by applications based on springboot.

Obviously the java-module does not have a class annotated with @SpringBootApplication.

Is it possible to test the functionality of the controller in the java-module anyway?

Until now, I have tried multiple things, but this is the closest I've got:

Note: Imports are left out for better readability.

```
    @SpringBootTest(classes = {ControllerTest.TestConfig.class}, webEnvironment =  SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
    @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
    @ActiveProfiles({"default", "test"})
    @Import(ControllerTest.TestConfig.class)

    class ControllerTest {
        @Test
        void test() {
            // Do a http request
        }

        @Configuration
        @ComponentScan("nl.example")
        public static class TestConfig {
        }
    }
```

When I run this test, I get the following error:

```
Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean.
```

Using spring boot version 2.1.11.RELEASE and spring version 5.1.11.RELEASE.

Comment: How about creating a `@SpringBootApplication` purely in test scope?

Comment: Yes, I have tried this, but it results in the same error.

Comment: Ok, it turned out I was using the wrong dependencies. Should have used spring-boot-starter-web instead of spring-web...